# Deduplicate a list from a file while keeping it in order -python3.5

Tags: list, duplicates, python-3.5, alphabetical

I am trying to open a file, split it, order it alphabetically and then remove duplicates. I have been able to open the file, split it, order it correctly, and put it in a list but then I am having trouble deduplicating it. How would I go about printing out a list that is in alphabetical order and deduplicated?

Here is what I currently have:

```
userinp = input('Enter file: ')
romeo = open(userinp)
inp = romeo.read()
sections = inp.split()
sections.sort()
shakespeare = list(sections)
for i in sections:
    if i not in shakespeare:
        shakespeare.append(i)
print(shakespeare)
```

Comment: im sort of having issues understanding what you want done.

Comment: Sorry about that. I am trying to take text from a file deduplicate the words and have it print out in alphabetical order. What I am having trouble with is getting it to deduplicate and have it be in alphabetical order. I am able to get one or the other, but not both. Does that make sense?

Comment: i mean, you can do that.  so with my answer for example, shows list duplication on a sorted array.  Are you trying to duplicate prior to the sort?

Comment: I am not trying to duplicate anything. I have a text that has repeating words and I am trying to only print out one of each word in alphabetical order.I am new to programming so I have trouble taking an example like yours below that uses defined lists and applying them to problems where I need to pull in text from a file.

Comment: Oh, only a unique set.  Ok.  i now know what you want.  Ill update my answer

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing a simple sample:

```
a = [9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]
for i in a:
  b[i] = 0
b = [x for x in b]
```

this will limit your result set.

In your code, using the same process:

```
userinp = input('Enter file: ')
romeo = open(userinp)
inp = romeo.read()
sections = inp.split()
shakespeare = {}
for i in sections:
  shakespeare[i] = 0
shakespeare = [x for x in b]
print(shakespeare)
```

the premise I had is:

- loop over array and inject into a map creating a unique key.
- then loop over the map, turning it back into a list.
- - this automatically sorted by walking the array in a sorted manor, but you can always just call .sort() to reconfirm if you so choose.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Say you have `file.txt` which contains

```
b
b
c
a
```

You can do

```
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    lines.sort()
    for line in OrderedDict.fromkeys(lines):
        print(line.strip())
```

Which will print out

```
a
b
c
```